# Draw arrow with text outside axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I want to draw an arrow with text that would stretch across several axes.  Reading http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html

I got that far :

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,3)
bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="rarrow,pad=0.2", fc="cyan", ec="b", lw=1)
t = ax[0,1].text(-0.8, 1.2, "Mag", ha="center", va="center", rotation=0, size=15, bbox=bbox_props)
```

which makes

[image: arrow]

I found from [text docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) that bbox is a dictionary of [Rectangle](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle), which has width and height,  but when I set

```
bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="rarrow,pad=0.2", fc="cyan", ec="b", lw=1, width=3)
t = ax[0,1].text(-0.8, 1.2, "Mag", ha="center", va="center", rotation=0, size=15, bbox=bbox_props)
```

I get a conflict :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-255-006733283545> in <module>()
     13 # properties of a rectangle : http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle
     14 
---> 15 t = ax[0,1].text(-0.8, 1.2, "Mag", ha="center", va="center", rotation=0, size=15, bbox=bbox_props)
     16 plt.savefig('example.png', bbox_inches='tight')

/Users/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in text(self, x, y, s, fontdict, withdash, **kwargs)
    626         if fontdict is not None:
    627             t.update(fontdict)
--> 628         t.update(kwargs)
    629 
    630         t.set_clip_path(self.patch)

/Users/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in update(self, kwargs)
    242         super(Text, self).update(kwargs)
    243         if bbox:
--> 244             self.set_bbox(bbox)  # depends on font properties
    245 
    246     def __getstate__(self):

/Users/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in set_bbox(self, rectprops)
    514                                     bbox_transmuter=bbox_transmuter,
    515                                     transform=mtransforms.IdentityTransform(),
--> 516                                     **props)
    517         else:
    518             self._bbox_patch = None

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'width'
```

How can I control the size of my arrow with bbox ? Is there a way to extend it all the way to the right?

Thank you! 
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to built our own `width` argument to a custom arrowstyle.
To this end we might subclass `BoxStyle.RArrow` and introduce a `width` argument in the newly created class `MyRArrow`.
The points of the arrow will then be offset by this width. In this simple example, `width` is in pixels. 
Finally, we might register this new class as a boxstyle `"myrarrow"`.

```
from matplotlib.patches import BoxStyle


class MyRArrow(BoxStyle.RArrow):
        def __init__(self, pad=0.3, width=220):
            self.width_ = width
            super(MyRArrow, self).__init__(pad)

        def transmute(self, x0, y0, width, height, mutation_size):
            p = BoxStyle.RArrow.transmute(self, x0, y0,
                                          width, height, mutation_size)
            x = p.vertices[:, 0]
            p.vertices[1:3, 0] = x[1:3] - self.width_
            p.vertices[0, 0]   = x[0]   + self.width_
            p.vertices[3:, 0]  = x[3:]  + self.width_
            return p

BoxStyle._style_list["myrarrow"] = MyRArrow
```

We can now use this new style and specify a `boxstyle="myrarrow,pad=0.2, width=150"` as bbox keyword argument.
It then also makes sense to specify the arrow position in figure coordinates instead of axes coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,3)
bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="myrarrow,pad=0.2, width=150", fc="cyan", ec="b", lw=1)
t = ax[0,1].text(0.5, 0.95, "Mag", ha="center", va="center", 
                rotation=0, size=15, bbox=bbox_props, transform=fig.transFigure)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a very neat solution, since the text stays centered on the arrow, and I can easily control its width. It's more complicated than I thought, but I learn something new about arrowstyles . That's great!

Answer (score 1):

It works if you add a bunch of spaces to both sides:

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,3)
ax = axes[0,0]
bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="rarrow, pad=0.2", fc="cyan", ec="b", lw=1)
t = ax.text(0.15,1.15,45*' '+'Mag'+45*' ', ha="left", va="center",
            size=15,bbox=bbox_props)
plt.show()
```

Resulting image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is very simple solution, and it works too. I really like it for the simplicity - it's a hack that does the job.  @Importance answer is very detailed, but more involved.   I'll use your answer for now because it is shorter, and keep the other one in my repository of very useful code.

Comment: Cheers, mate :-) Please accept one of our answers with the checkmark so people know this is answered.